# Does effect size mean anything when when the t-test is not significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, effect-size

I have two sets of data and I would like to have a metric that says something about how different the sets are. I use Cohen's $d$ measure. Let's say $d=0.5$, but $p=0.32$. What does it mean?

Comment: It means lots of things, p is effectively an indicator of signal to noise on the data. A low p value may mean the effect can be ignored or it may mean that there are serious noise issues that need sorted or it may mean that more extensive data collection is required. It is advisable to determine what is a minimum meaningful effect size (which is very context specific) independently of statistical analysis. Once that is done it will help guide you whether the problem is that the measured effect is too small, the noise is too high or the observations too few.